# Append and Read Same File - Python

Tags: python

Stuck on this school question, what am I missing?

> *"Objective: Complete the function to append the given new data to the specified file then print the contents of the file"*

On of my many attempts:

```
import os
def appendAndPrint(filename, newData):
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f = f.write(newData)
        r = f.read()
        print(r)
```

> *Test case,  expected output: Hello World*

```
with open("test.txt", 'w') as f: 
    f.write("Hello ")
appendAndPrint("test.txt", "World")
```

If I get the interpreter to not throw an error, on several attempts it would simply print 5.

Comment: Make sure to click the check next to the most helpful answer!

Answer (score 3):

This code should work:

```
def append_and_print(filename, new_data):
    with open(filename, "a") as f:
        f.write(new_data)
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        print(f.read())
```

Comment: I completely overlooked the fact I can have multiple with statements in the same function. Thanks!

Comment: @OccamsBlazer take a look at the other answers. This answer neither explained the actual problem, nor gave you an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file with `a+` to also give your program read permissions:

```
import os
def appendAndPrint(filename, newData):
    with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
        f.write(newData)
        f.seek(0)
        r=f.read()
        print(r)
...
```

edit: as commenters pointed out, you need to seek to the 0 position in the file so that you can read the whole thing

Comment: Thanks for this, I actually did have the + in there the several times I got the interpreter to run without the error. My final attempts before I posted here I omitted the + but was still consistently getting errors, so something other than the opening arguments was off and thats the part thats confusing me. TLDR, assume I had the + in there

Comment: @OccamsBlazer looking over your code again I realized you set the variable `f` to `f.write(newData)`
That would make it so that `f` is the `None` object rather than the `file` object like it should be.

Comment: You haven't shown how to do the read part. That's half of the problem.

Comment: @tdelaney `r = f.read()` is perfectly fine. What do you mean? Edit: no it's not lol

Comment: @FourInchKnife That won't read anything because at that line the cursor is at the end.

Comment: @FourInchKnife - If its fine, then add it to the answer. But its not fine - you will not read any data because the file pointer is at the end of file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `a+` mode for reading/writing.
After you append using `write`,
you can move the cursor to the initial position using `seek` method,
then read it from the beginning.

```py
def appendAndPrint(filename, newData):
    with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
        f.write(newData)
        f.seek(0)
        print(f.read())


with open("test.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write("Hello ")
appendAndPrint("test.txt", "World")
```

```
Hello World
```